# Rebuild index on Hive fails

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I am using the HortonWorks sandbox to explore some functionality with Hive and imported a table into it using Sqoop.

Since it was a fairly large table, I tried to create an index on one of the columns. It asked me to add the "`WITH DEFERRED REBUILD`" option which I did and the index was created.

But when I tried to rebuild the index, the job failed with the following log.

**Logs**

```
Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:137)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:337)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:179)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:171)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:171)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:167)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.<init>(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.getRecordReader(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:97)
    at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.lib.MRReaderMapred.setupOldRecordReader(MRReaderMapred.java:149)
    at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.lib.MRReaderMapred.setSplit(MRReaderMapred.java:80)
    at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.input.MRInput.initFromEventInternal(MRInput.java:614)
    at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.input.MRInput.initFromEvent(MRInput.java:593)
    at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.input.MRInputLegacy.checkAndAwaitRecordReaderInitialization(MRInputLegacy.java:141)
    at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.input.MRInputLegacy.init(MRInputLegacy.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.getMRInput(MapRecordProcessor.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:147)
    ... 14 more

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.init(HiveInputFormat.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(HiveInputFormat.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:189)
    ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was encountering the same problem. I found a workaround

```
set hive.execution.engine=mr;
alter index index_name on table_name rebuild;
set hive.execution.engine=tez;
```

Running the rebuild of the index using MR worked for me without a problem. I am not sure why TEZ fails.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to a mis configured memory parameter in tez actually.

That is why switching to mr solved the problem.

A good article on tez memory was very useful in debugging this problem.

https://community.hortonworks.com/content/kbentry/14309/demystify-tez-tuning-step-by-step.html